# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock not opening bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, updatepanel

Hi I am having a lot of trouble. I have a bootstrap modal which I am trying to open from server side code(c#) in ASP.net. I have seen other posts about this but I am still finding trouble.

aspx.cs page

```
private void message(){

ModalBody.Text = "You have reached your credit limit";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(),"myModal","$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);
            upModal.Update();
}
```

ASPX page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">xxxxxx</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:Label ID="ModalBody" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="ModalBody2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

</ContentTemplate>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have noticed that when I move

```
ModalBody.Text = "You have reached your credit limit";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(),"myModal","$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);
            upModal.Update();
```

this section into the Page_load method it works fine and the popup is shown with the text. I have even stepped through but it doesn't do much and even looked at the console.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script manager is to manages ASP.NET ajax script libraries and script files, partial page rendering. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863(v=vs.100).aspx You can added to your master page or the page you needs.

Comment: Yes that has already been added to all the pages, every page works fine but this one.